# PHP Loop date by Month

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date

Having a PEBKAC on this date array... I can't figure out why first position of second dimension overwrites with the last modification of the date... All help is much appreciated!

```
$year=date('Y');
$count=date('m'); //loop from begining of current year to current month

$begin =new DateTime("$year-01-01");
$end = clone $begin;


for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if ($i >0){ 
        $begin=$begin->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
        $end = clone $begin;
    }
    $dateArray[$i][0]=$begin;
    $dateArray[$i][1]=$end->modify('last day of this month');
}
```

The output I am looking for is to have a multi dimensional array that has the first date and last date of each month from current year to current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing a reference to `$begin` and then updating `$begin` on each loop. Clone `$begin` when you are assigning it to your array:

```
$dateArray[$i][0] = clone $begin;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$year  =date('Y');
$count =date('m'); //loop from begining of current year to current month

$begin = new DateTime("$year-01-01");
$end   = clone $begin;

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if ($i >0){ 
        $begin = $begin->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
        $end   = clone $begin;
    }
    $dateArray[$i][0]=clone $begin;
    $dateArray[$i][1]=$end->modify('last day of this month');
}
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )

        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-01-31 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )

        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-02-28 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-03-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-03-31 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-04-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-04-30 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-05-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-05-31 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-06-30 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-07-01 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-07-31 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
            )
    )
)
```